# Error in user authentication process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, password-encryption

I'm trying to recreate a user authentication process in a new application.  I have an old, existing user authentication that works, and I literally copied the code (changing the names of course) over expecting it to be a good starting point... However it does not work!  I have tried everything, but for some reason I can't log in on this program... perhaps there is something I'm overlooking?

login.html.erb

```
<div class="login" style="margin-left: 390px;">
  <%= form_tag(:action => 'team_login') do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:username) %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag(:username) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:password) %></td>
      <td><%= password_field_tag(:password) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= submit_tag("Log In") %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

teams_controller.rb

```
  def team_login
    authorized_team = Team.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    if authorized_team
      #To Do: mark user as logged in
      session[:team_id] = authorized_team.id
      session[:team_name] = authorized_team.username
      #check!
      flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in."
      redirect_to(:controller => 'show', :id => session[:team_id])
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid username and password combination"
      redirect_to(:action => 'login')
    end
  end
```

team.rb

```
  attr_accessible :username, :password

  attr_accessor :password

  before_save :create_hashed_password

  def self.authenticate(username="", password="")
    qTeam = Team.find_by_username(username)
    if qTeam && qTeam.password_match?(password)
      return qTeam
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def password_match?(password="")
    hashed == Team.salt_hash(salt, password)
  end

  def self.make_salt(username="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(" #{username} #{Time.now}")
  end

  def self.salt_hash(salt="", password="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt} #{password}")
  end

  private

  def create_hashed_password
    unless password.blank?
      self.salt = Team.make_salt(username) if salt.blank?
      self.hashed = Team.salt_hash(password, salt)
    end
  end
```

---

I realized that the error is occurring when creating the user.  If I go in manually and use the salt saved to the user, the password, and generate a hashed password, it is different than the one that is saved in the database.  I assume that this is where the error is occurring - the template that I'm using to create the user is just the standard _form generated from a scaffold.  All the code is the same as above - before_save runs through a a few methods (create_hashed_password, make_salt, and salt_hash)

Comment: Did you try using `form_for` instead of `form_tag`, it might help you on sending the form using REST architecture. Also, did you check if the form submission hits the server correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have:

```
:action => 'team_login'
```

pointing to a route that works.

I usually use something like:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
...
<% end %>
```

With a route that appears like:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "sessions/new"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  resources :sessions
  ...
end
```

With a sessions_controller that looks like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = login(params[:email], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
    if user
      redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Welcome, #{user.email}."
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Forgetting to wire up routing is a common mishap when copy/pasting functionality, such as authentication, from one app to another.

Comment: thanks @Timothy Britt definitely a lot of good information!  Very clean code - I'll probably restructure the final code to something similar to what you posted :D.  I posted an update though - seems the problem wasn't in the login code (or I can't tell yet) but instead the hashing of the password.